# What's on your C++ cheatsheet?

Tags: c++

Every so often, I'll have to switch between languages for the majority of the code I write (whether for work or for play).  I find that C++ is one of those languages that requires a lot of mental cache space, so if I take a long break from it, then I forget a lot of the details. Even things like adding items to an STL container or using the `static` storage keyword in various contexts get all jumbled up ("is it `add`, `append`, `push`...oh, it's `push_back`").

So what essential tidbits do you like to have loaded into your brain when you're writing C++?

Edit: I should say, I'd like to be able to bookmark this page and use it as my cheatsheet :)

Comment: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat

Answer (score 18):

When I switch back from Java to C++, I like to review items from [C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu.

Scott Meyers' [Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) series are great for this too.

Here are quick basic stuffs that work for me:

- Use [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)
- "When in doubt, do as the ints do." (Scott Meyers)
- `const *` means constant data, `* const` means constant pointer (read the decl. backwards!).
- Declare an assignment operator and a copy constructor in classes with dynamically assigned data.
- C++ will write an assignment operator & copy constructor for you if you don't declare one yourself. Except if you declare them (private, most likely) and omit to define them.
- Have operator=() return a reference to `*this`
- Call Base(rhs) in Derived's copy constructor's init list.
- Call `Base::operator=(rhs);` in Derived's `operator=()`
- Check for assignment to self in `operator=()`
- Don't implement `operator=()` by calling the copy constructor (Herb Sutter, [Write what you Know, and Know what you Write](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/advice97.htm))
- Remember [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)
- catch exceptions by reference

Answer (score 15):

On my cheatsheet: interactions between const and pointers:

```
int       *       p;  // pointer
int const *       p;  // pointer to const value
int       * const p;  // const pointer
int const * const p;  // const pointer to const value
```

Essentially, split the declaration on the `*` symbol and if the const falls to the left, the pointed-to value is const, and if it falls to the right, the pointer itself is const.

Comment: I saw a great response on SO about how to remember these, you just have to read them backwards.

i.e.

int * const p -- p is a const pointer to an int
int const * p -- p is a pointer to a const int.

Comment: yeah, that's a good trick as well.

Comment: Another way to look at `int const * p` is *p is const i.e. value at address in p is const and not the pointer itself. Similarly `const p` implies the pointer itself is const.

Comment: It's not complicated: _const applies to the left (unless there's nothing there, in which case it applies to the right)_

Answer (score 9):

I keep a PDF of the C++ standard open.  It's good for quickly looking up all the library interfaces (particularly the container interfaces and iostream stuff).  It's also useful for quickly resolving co-workers' arguments about C++ syntax and semantics.

I haven't yet figured out how to load the PDF into my brain.

Comment: If you succeed in loading the PDF into your brain, I'll be interested too! :)

Comment: I took the HTML version (I was on the Standards committee for a while), and made it into a Microsoft Reader file. Keep it on my PocketPC for easy access on the go!

Comment: This is a good thing to do, allows for searching which is very helpful

Comment: +1 for that. It might seem like overkill to non-C++ programmers, but it's really the only sane approach to the language.

Answer (score 6):

Since I work in C++ all the time I keep most of the syntax in my head. For library reference I use [sgi](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl) and [Josuttis'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260) book. When I haven't done C++ for a while and really want a refresher I go back to [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876).

When I need to ansewer a deeper question I'll refer to the standard or [Stroustrup's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735) book.

When all else fails, google and stackoverflow are great tools.

Answer (score 5):

### Implementing a Callback to a non-static C++ Member Function

Every time I have to do this I need to look this one up. Really anything that deals with function pointer details always tends to tweak my brain. I've found the [Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) to be a fairly good reference.

Comment: More than I'd like to admit for our internal implementation of signals. I could use boost for some of this but some projects won't allow for it. :(

Answer (score 5):

On my C Cheatsheet (and on the C++ one by extension), pointer to function syntax.

Comment: For C++, the pointer-to-member-function syntax is something I always have to look up when I use it.

Answer (score 4):

Not really on a cheat sheet, and not really specific to C++, but I have "Flush the buffer!" on a sticky note to remind me of what's probably wrong when I'm not receiving data.

Answer (score 4):

I keep this whole site handy for cheatsheets in general:

http://www.cheat-sheets.org/#CPP

The cpp cheatsheet is a bit basic, but the STL is useful.

Answer (score 3):

I use the site [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/).  It is a great reference for C and C++ programming.

Comment: Actually, [it's not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad).

Answer (score 2):

Template specialization. I always need to look it up.

Answer (score 2):

I have a little copy of the operator precedence chart tacked to my cube wall.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Meyer's TR1 summary page, http://www.aristeia.com/EC3E/TR1_info.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as operators are concerned, [cpp.operator-precedence.com](http://cpp.operator-precedence.com)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the thing that gets me the most switching between C# & C++ is constructor syntax.  (I keep wanting to use "new" for everything).

Answer (score 0):

[Dinkumware Compleat Reference](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/) for STL and other standard <include>s.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a quick reference and recap , here are C++ Cheat Sheet

[C++ cheat sheet - part 1](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/11/22/c-cheat-sheet-1/) 
[C++ cheat sheet - part 2](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/11/22/c-cheat-sheet-part-2/)

Answer (score -1):

Access to Google and the ability to type suffices for me.

Admittedly I am spoilt by having near-guaranteed web access in my working environment. Failing that for whatever reason, I have all three standard PDFs lying around too.

The downside of this is a high guess/knowledge ratio during factual Q&A sections in C++ interviews. The upside is that I am very good at the job that I have. :P