# Is there any cheatsheet available for C++?

Tags: c++

What do you like to have in the C++ cheat sheet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175244/whats-on-your-c-cheatsheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20090823155413/http://www.sfu.ca/~vwchu/projects/CPPQuickRef.pdf) that seems to be detailed enough.

It covers basics of templates, inheritance, operators, exceptions, etc. It has a lot of information in a very small space.

Answer (score 2):

The O'Reilly book [C++ Pocket Reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004965/) would be one such useful tool.

> The C++ Pocket Reference is a memory
>   aid for C++ programmers, enabling them
>   to quickly look up usage and syntax
>   for unfamiliar and infrequently used
>   aspects of the language. The book's
>   small size makes it easy to carry
>   about, ensuring that it will always be
>   at-hand when needed. Programmers will
>   also appreciate the book's brevity; as
>   much information as possible has been
>   crammed into its small pages.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the [SparkCharts C++ cheat sheet](http://sparkcharts.sparknotes.com/cs/cplusplus/).  I found it at a Borders, but you can print it out online for the same price.

Answer (score 2):

[CPP_Language_Reference](http://interviewpattern.com/Resources/CPP_Language_Reference.pdf)

[CppQuickReference](http://interviewpattern.com/Resources/CppQuickReference.pdf)